# Database is locked -sqlite3

Tags: iphone, sqlite

-(void) dropCategories{

```
        if (deleteCategoryStmt == nil) {
            const char *deleteSql = "delete from tb_category";
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, deleteSql, -1, &deleteCategoryStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
                    NSAssert1(0,@"Error in preparing drop category statement with '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            else 
                    NSLog(@"NO error in creating drop categories statement");


        }

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteCategoryStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while drop category data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(deleteCategoryStmt);  
    //sqlite3_finalize(deleteCategoryStmt);
    deleteCategoryStmt = nil;
}
```

Call to this function once works fine but whenever i calls it again it terminates giving the below exception.

Any suggestion Why is such happening?

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[Category dropCategories], /Users/rsplmac/Documents/LiteApp2/Classes/Category.m:171
2010-08-17 14:01:06.648 LiteApp2[4335:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while drop category data. 'database is locked''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02429919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x025775de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x023e2078 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x000ce8cf -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   LiteApp2                            0x000043ce -[Category dropCategories] + 462
    5   LiteApp2                            0x00004ba3 -[RootViewController updateMe:] + 1297
    6   UIKit                               0x002d3e14 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    7   UIKit                               0x004db14b -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
    8   UIKit                               0x002d3e14 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    9   UIKit                               0x0035d6c8 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    10  UIKit                               0x0035fb4a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    11  UIKit                               0x0035e6f7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    12  UIKit                               0x002f72ff -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    13  UIKit                               0x002d91ec -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    14  UIKit                               0x002ddac4 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7495
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x02c15afa PurpleEventCallback + 1578
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0240adc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0236b737 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x023689c3 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x02368280 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023681a1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x02c142c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x02c1438d GSEventRun + 115
    23  UIKit                               0x002e1b58 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    24  LiteApp2                            0x00002808 main + 102
    25  LiteApp2                            0x00002799 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `sqlite3_finalize` appears to be commented. A complete call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is usually followed by `sqlite_step` then `sqlite3_finalize`. Can you try that, without `sqlite3_reset`?

EDIT: For posterity: asker found the real cause, the database was locked by another object. Above function was fine.

Comment: I have tried it but still doesn't seems to be working.Still terminating the application. Is there any way that i forcefully unlock the database or clear all the previous lock?

Hope that can solve my problem.

Comment: Hmmm... did you try `sqlite3_exec`? All-in-one query execution!

Comment: i finally found that the problem was with my code.
I have opened database with 2 different objects.. Finaly sorted it out

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get to have the right answer here, you do.

Comment: hmm actually i have selected your answer coz its too is correct. and thats the proper way of implementation. The problem was with my code and as per question you were correct according. Your answer dint solved my problem but it will solve the problem of others having the same problem but not the same mistake as i did.. ;)

Comment: what was the mistake which u did