# sqlite3 - iOS - database is locked

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I am developing an app for ipad and i am using sqlite sentences (select, update, insert, delete).

I open (sqlite3_open) the database at the beginning and close (sqlite3_close) at the end of each sentence. But sometimes i´ve got the "database is locked" message.

I don´t know what can i do to solve this.

Thanks and sorry for this little information.

Comment: You will need to provide more information, like where is the database located and on what queries do you get the "locked" messages, how do you query the database, do you close your results set. There is just not engough to go on. The only thing I can think of now is that the database file is readonly because it's in the app bundle (resources).

Comment: Possible duplicated [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500635/database-is-locked-sqlite3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken , the problem with sqllite is that you can only access it once at a time.
If you have multiple threads, you can run in this situation. Example:

Run method1 (which accesses the database) on thread t1.
Run method2 (which accesses the database) on thread t2 after x seconds.

If method1 is not finished in those x seconds , both methods will access it at the same time.
And , as I said , I know that sqllite does not support this.

You should try to flag the usage of your database and if you want to access it but it is in use , try again after x seconds. Like this:

```
- (void) generalMethodThatUsesDatabses
{
    if(databaseIsUsed)
    {
         [self performSelector:@selector(generalMethodThatUsesDatabses) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
          return;
    }

    databaseIsUsed = TRUE;   //global bool variable


    //your code here

    databaseIsUsed = FALSE;

}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: thanks, I will check all the code and use yours flags ;) I will comment when i get some result

Comment: I think this is the case because you said that this only happens "sometimes" . So it could be dependable of the amount of information and thus , the time that a certain action takes.

Comment: thanks, thanks a lot!! ;) thanks to the flags i have been able to found the mistakes, one was that i open the DB inside another sentence, and the another mistake is that i had an "return" inside the sentence withour close the DB

Comment: Glad to help. Indeed , using a protocol is much better . scheduling after x seconds as I wrote makes you lose x-1 seconds in the worst case scenario. Even if that would be around 3-4 seconds , it's still a freeze that you don't want.

Comment: If blocking wait is acceptable, you could also use the `@synchronized` scope around DB access.

Comment: Using extra variable does not assure thread safety. You need yo use synchronised from fw

Answer (score 3):

You probably opened the database before using the same simulator.
To conclude all actions to a database and release all resources you always
have to use both (!) statements:

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: A lot of starters only include the sqlite3_close statement assuming that the finalize is automatically executed during the close. Which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve this is to wrap this into a C++ library. This way, you can can create the library wrapper on the stack. This means that the moment that the function goes out of scope, you can close the connection in the destructor.

(note that I use reference counting for the Objective-C)

For instance:

```
NSArray* ScoreBoard::getAllScores()
{ 
      ScoreBoard::ensureExistingTable();

      //Stack allocated
      SqliteWrapper sqlite("Scores.sqlite");

     NSArray* result = sqlite.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM Scores ORDER BY ID DESC");

     return result;
     //after this, the sqlite destructor is called
}
```

It is very nice that the Objective-C compiler allows you to merge C++. It can be extremely useful.

Also

```
 void SqliteWrapper::Close()
 {
     sqlite3_close(db);
 }
```

as Vincent has pointed out, you have to finalize the statement. If you want keep the connection open, use finalize after each statement. Close out the connection the moment you are discarding the connection.

This method works for me.

Answer (score -1):

it is use for three methed
1.isert
2.update
3. delete.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)resultSet
-(void)insertWithTitle:(NSString *)title Body:(NSString *)body
-(BOOL)updateAtIndex:(int)index Title:(NSString *)title Body:(NSString *)body

NSMutableArray *result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autorelease];

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:[self SQL:@"SELECT * FROM %@" inTable:TABLE_NAME]];
while ([rs next]) {
    Record *tr = [[Record alloc] initWithIndex:[rs intForColumn:@"id"]
                                         Title:[rs stringForColumn:@"title"]
                                          Body:[rs stringForColumn:@"body"]];
    [result addObject:tr];
    [tr release];
}

[rs close];
```

2....

```
return result;
[db executeUpdate:[self SQL:@"INSERT INTO %@ (title, body) VALUES (?,?)" inTable:TABLE_NAME], title, body];
if ([db hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"Err %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
```

Delete record :

```
BOOL success = YES;
[db executeUpdate:[self SQL:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE id = ?" inTable:TABLE_NAME], [NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];
if ([db hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"Err %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    success = NO;
}
return success;

}
```